# Match all directory names in file path with regular expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Can someone give me the regular expression to match something like `/this/is/the/path` or `/this/is/the/path/` and matches like:

```
$1=this
$2=is
$3=the
$4=path
```

`([^/]+)/` matches one, but I'm not quite sure how to get it to repeat.

FYI: this is for a mod rewrite RewriteRule match.

Comment: `((?:[^/]+)/)+` will match your path (watch out for `?:` extension, may bite you if it doesn't exist), but I'm not sure if it will capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want defined, numbered groups, you must repeat it yourself:

```
/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?

  this     is     the     path
```

Answer (score 0):

If mod-rewrite supports it ([^/]+){1,4} should match from 1 to 4 groups. Adapt numbers as needed/desired.